# How to put insert automatically an email address in BCC for all send message from a shared mailbox in Outlook 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Within an Office 365 subscription, considering a list of users (all from the same organization) who are using a *shared mailbox* in Outlook, I would like to have the shared mailbox configured so that a hard-coded email address is automatically added as BCC to all the emails sent from this shared mailbox. How can I do that?

Ps: The BCC recipient is a 3rd party CRM software. Putting all the messages in BCC make them appear in the CRM.

Comment: Do suggestion above help? If the suggestion is helpful to you, you could mark the reply as best answer or share your solution, your action will be helpful to other people who encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure a transport rule in exchange server side:
[image]